# Not able to use TestNG test annotation without providing full package name

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, testng

In the latest Intellij IDEA Ultimate, i'm not able to use the @Test annotation without getting red error lines. Only way it works is if I provide the full package name like below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Test {
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void setup(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/jeff/IdeaProjects/Practice/src/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
}

@org.testng.annotations.Test
public void test(){
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("Hello World");
    searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown() throws Exception{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

The other annotations work fine as you can see. And since I have the options *Add unambiguous imports on the fly* and *optimize imports on the fly* checked in the preferences, when I go ahead and add the following:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

It gets greyed out since it's not in use...but it is.

Here is my maven pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>Practice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you try to remove junit from your classpath?

Comment: @juherr, still doesn't seem to work even after I remove junit. It seems that even when I do an auto generate for a test method, it still uses the full package name for the annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is named `Test` itself, hence the fully qualified annotation class name is required to prevent the conflict. Rename the class to `SomeTest` and you will be able to use `@Test` annotation with import.